# Is there any way to use Google search API to find Web 2.0 deadlinks?

Tags: php

I am creating a web application based on PHP to find web 2.0 deadlinks.
The application will search for tumblr.com to get the expired website links.

I have integrated google search API to get the result for any specific site which includes the sub-domains but I am only getting the active link, not the deadlinks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to write effective questions. I recommend you to add some piece of code. Then we can try to fix it or give you an advice.

Comment: Thank you @Teocci, but I am not expecting any codes. Just asking is it possible to do via PHP or not? If it's possible, so any ideas about how I can do that?